# Controller not syncing after charging and resetting

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

My ps4 is stuck in the “press ps button to use the controller” screen. My controllers are charged, I tried to hit the reset button and unplugging the console for a minute- that didn’t work. - still just flashing blue. Anything else I could try?